# Draw transparent rectangles and polygons in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

How can I draw a rectangle that has a color with an alpha?
I have:

```
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 750), pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, pygame.Color(255, 255, 255, 128), pygame.Rect(0, 0, 1000, 750))
```

But I want the white rectangle to be 50% transparent, but the alpha value doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: You need to add more code, as the above line seems fine. Either there is something wrong with window initialization so that it doesn't support alpha, or you are actually drawing the rect multiple times without clearing the screen so that the rect appears opaque.

Comment: Do you need the pygame.init too?

Comment: Hmm, since you are not explicitly specifying bit depth, you might try `windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 750), pygame.DOUBLEBUF, 32)`. Only 32bit surfaces support alpha channel.

Comment: You need to add more code then. Can you post your main loop where you do the drawing?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

`pygame.draw` functions will not draw with alpha. The documentation says:

> Most of the arguments accept a color argument that is an RGB triplet. These can also accept an RGBA quadruplet. The alpha value will be written directly into the Surface if it contains pixel alphas, but the draw function will not draw transparently.

What you can do is create a second surface and then blit it to the screen. Blitting will do alpha blending and color keys. Also, you can specify alpha at the surface level (faster and less memory) or at the pixel level (slower but more precise). You can do either:

```
s = pygame.Surface((1000,750))  # the size of your rect
s.set_alpha(128)                # alpha level
s.fill((255,255,255))           # this fills the entire surface
windowSurface.blit(s, (0,0))    # (0,0) are the top-left coordinates
```

or,

```
s = pygame.Surface((1000,750), pygame.SRCALPHA)   # per-pixel alpha
s.fill((255,255,255,128))                         # notice the alpha value in the color
windowSurface.blit(s, (0,0))
```

Keep in mind in the first case, that anything else you draw to `s` will get blitted with the alpha value you specify. So if you're using this to draw overlay controls for example, you might be better off using the second alternative.

Also, consider using pygame.HWSURFACE to create the surface hardware-accelerated.

Check the [Surface docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) at the pygame site, especially the intro.

Answer (score 22):

Unfortunately there is no good way to draw a transparent shape. See [pygame.draw](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html) module:

> A color's alpha value will be written directly into the surface [...], but the draw function will not draw transparently.

So you can't draw transparent shapes directly with the 'pygame.draw' module. The 'pygame.draw' module does not blend the shape with the target surface. You have to draw the shape on a surface (with RGBA format). Then you can `blit` (and thus blend) this surface. See [Draw a transparent rectangles and polygons in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339057/draw-a-transparent-rectangles-and-polygons-in-pygame/64630102#64630102). Hence you need to do a workaround:

1. Create a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object with a per-pixel alpha format large enough to cover the shape.
2. Draw the shape on the _Surface.
3. Blend the *Surface* with the target *Surface*. [`blit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) by default blends 2 *Surfaces*

For example 3 functions, which can draw transparent rectangles, circles and polygons:

```py
def draw_rect_alpha(surface, color, rect):
    shape_surf = pygame.Surface(pygame.Rect(rect).size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
    pygame.draw.rect(shape_surf, color, shape_surf.get_rect())
    surface.blit(shape_surf, rect)
```

```py
def draw_circle_alpha(surface, color, center, radius):
    target_rect = pygame.Rect(center, (0, 0)).inflate((radius * 2, radius * 2))
    shape_surf = pygame.Surface(target_rect.size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
    pygame.draw.circle(shape_surf, color, (radius, radius), radius)
    surface.blit(shape_surf, target_rect)
```

```py
def draw_polygon_alpha(surface, color, points):
    lx, ly = zip(*points)
    min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = min(lx), min(ly), max(lx), max(ly)
    target_rect = pygame.Rect(min_x, min_y, max_x - min_x, max_y - min_y)
    shape_surf = pygame.Surface(target_rect.size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
    pygame.draw.polygon(shape_surf, color, [(x - min_x, y - min_y) for x, y in points])
    surface.blit(shape_surf, target_rect)
```

---

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-TransparentShapes](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-TransparentShapes#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame

def draw_rect_alpha(surface, color, rect):
    shape_surf = pygame.Surface(pygame.Rect(rect).size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
    pygame.draw.rect(shape_surf, color, shape_surf.get_rect())
    surface.blit(shape_surf, rect)

def draw_circle_alpha(surface, color, center, radius):
    target_rect = pygame.Rect(center, (0, 0)).inflate((radius * 2, radius * 2))
    shape_surf = pygame.Surface(target_rect.size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
    pygame.draw.circle(shape_surf, color, (radius, radius), radius)
    surface.blit(shape_surf, target_rect)

def draw_polygon_alpha(surface, color, points):
    lx, ly = zip(*points)
    min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = min(lx), min(ly), max(lx), max(ly)
    target_rect = pygame.Rect(min_x, min_y, max_x - min_x, max_y - min_y)
    shape_surf = pygame.Surface(target_rect.size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
    pygame.draw.polygon(shape_surf, color, [(x - min_x, y - min_y) for x, y in points])
    surface.blit(shape_surf, target_rect)

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((250, 250))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

background = pygame.Surface(window.get_size())
ts, w, h, c1, c2 = 50, *window.get_size(), (160, 160, 160), (192, 192, 192)
tiles = [((x*ts, y*ts, ts, ts), c1 if (x+y) % 2 == 0 else c2) for x in range((w+ts-1)//ts) for y in range((h+ts-1)//ts)]
for rect, color in tiles:
    pygame.draw.rect(background, color, rect)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.blit(background, (0, 0))

    draw_rect_alpha(window, (0, 0, 255, 127), (55, 90, 140, 140))
    draw_circle_alpha(window, (255, 0, 0, 127), (150, 100), 80)
    draw_polygon_alpha(window, (255, 255, 0, 127), 
        [(100, 10), (100 + 0.8660 * 90, 145), (100 - 0.8660 * 90, 145)])

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: This `draw_polygon_alpha` function is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

the most i can do to help you is to show you how to draw a rectangle that is not filled in.
the line for the rectangle is:

```
pygame.draw.rect(surface, [255, 0, 0], [50, 50, 90, 180], 1)
```

the "1" means that it is not filled in

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, but helped me to draw a bordered transparent rect :D

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is to instead of drawing a rectangle with pygame, you could create an image of a transparent rectangle by using a drawing program such as paint.net or Fire Alpaca.